# git push failes with "access denied" error on gitlab 7

Tags: gitlab

When I try to push (from an existing repo) to a new repository on a freshly installed Gitlab CE instance I get an error:

`Access Denied.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

Strange thing is that pushing actually works for the first repository I created. The second repository gives this error.

I installed Gitlab (gitlab_7.3.2-omnibus-1_amd64.deb) on a fresh DigitalOcean instance (1GB ram) on Debian 7 x64.

An `ssh -vT git@[domain]` command gives ok: *Welcome to GitLab, Ruurd Adema!*

Any ideas of what's going on?

*Edit:* when tying to clone the second (empty) repo I get this error:

`fatal: '/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/ruurdadema/encoder.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

Checking the repositories folder tells me that the repository isn't there, but the wiki of the project is indeed there.

*Edit:* I found this error in the log of omnibus 7.4.2:

`E, [2014-10-24T21:09:32.502741 #11717] ERROR -- : API call <POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v3/internal/allowed> failed: 500 => <{"message"=>"500 Internal Server Error"}>.`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have the same public key registered twice (on two different projects).

The [issue 6908](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/6908) mentions:

> I had two identical keys on two different projects, but added them separately, it worked before but all of a sudden I get the 'access denied' on `git pull`.
>   I tried to delete both keys but the key was not removed from `authorized_keys` file, so I removed the line manually and added the deploy key again.
>   Now I added one key and **on the second project I just enabled the existing key**.
>
> Maybe this is not a bug anymore but I in my opinion the authorized_keys file should be cleaned more carefully.

Comment: Thanks. I checked to be sure, I don't have any deploy key on any project.
In the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys there's only the one key I added to my user profile.